# Debug CakePHP on Eclipse

Tags: cakephp

What is the best way to debug CakePHP with Eclipse? I download the ZendDebugger plugins and 
debug normal PHP application which get debug fine.

But debugging application like CakePHP (having MVC pattern) gives the error while debugging.

So what is correct way to debug CakePHP application on Elicpse.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use DebugKit for debugging my cake projects as it gives you all the info you need in a really nice way.

Check it out, https://www.ohloh.net/p/cakephp-debugkit

I understand this isn't a solution specifically for Eclipse, but debugging problems in your code might be easier with turning PHP errors on.

```
ini_set('display_errors','On');
ini_set('error_reporting',E_ALL);
```

Also be sure to turn the debug setting in `app/config/core.php` to `2` to get a full debug output.

Comment: Thanks for this solution.. but I also tried this one which debug the whole php page. But in this case we can't set breakpoints into application to test it line by line.

Comment: Using DebugKit will not add any break points into the code. I think we are crossing lines, as I tend to debug my code by seeing how a browser renders it, rather than debugging in my IDE :)